# CouchDB Reduce Function

Tags: couchdb, reduce

I've defined a map function in CouchDB that produces data that looks like this:-

```
 var data =
{"total_rows":10,"offset":0,"rows":[
    {"id":"338b79f07dfe8b3877b3aa41a5bb8a58","key":"2000-06-23T23:59:00+00:00","value":{"country":"United States"}},
    {"id":"338b79f07dfe8b3877b3aa41a5bb983e","key":"2000-06-23T23:59:00+00:00","value":{"country":"Norway"}},
    {"id":"338b79f07dfe8b3877b3aa41a5ddfefe","key":"2000-06-23T23:59:00+00:00","value":{"country":"Hungary"}},
    {"id":"338b79f07dfe8b3877b3aa41a5fe29d7","key":"2000-06-23T23:59:00+00:00","value":{"country":"United States"}},
    {"id":"b6ed02fb38d6506d7371c419751e8a14","key":"2000-06-23T23:59:00+00:00","value":{"country":"Germany"}},
    {"id":"b6ed02fb38d6506d7371c419753e20b6","key":"2000-06-23T23:59:00+00:00","value":{"country":"Hungary"}},
    {"id":"b6ed02fb38d6506d7371c419755f34ad","key":"2000-06-23T23:59:00+00:00","value":{"country":"United States"}},
    {"id":"b6ed02fb38d6506d7371c419755f3e17","key":"2000-06-23T23:59:00+00:00","value":{"country":"Germany"}},
    {"id":"338b79f07dfe8b3877b3aa41a506082f","key":"2003-01-08T19:34:00+00:00","value":{"country":"United Kingdom"}},
    {"id":"9366afb036bf8b63c9f45379bbe29509","key":"2003-01-08T19:34:00+00:00","value":{"":"United Kingdom"}}
]
}
```

I'm now trying to create reduce function that produces data that looks like this:-

```
{"rows":[
{"key":"United States","value":2},
{"key":"Norway","value":1},
{"key":"Hungary","value":2},
{"key":"Germany","value":2}
{"key":"United Kingdom","value":1}

]}
```

I need to the ability to use the "StartKey" and "EndKey" parameters in couch to define the date ranges. This is proving trickier than I expected. Can somebody show me what my reduce function should look like to handle this?

Regards,

Carlskii

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid there is a common anti-pattern of using map reduce.

Please read [Example 3, “Don’t use this, it’s an example broken on purpose”](http://guide.couchdb.org/editions/1/en/views.html#example/3)